# Retrieve & Display different rows of a Mysql table to a GUI form in java

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, jdbc

I want to retrieve rows from my database one by one and view it in jtextfields present in a GUI form which I made. I am able to retrieve the first row, but never the second or third or fourth,etc.

Please help. If you need more information please ask

```
String SQL = "select CATEGORY,ITEM,QTY,Avg_Price from (select CATEGORY,ITEM,QTY,AVG_PRICE, rownum rw     from final_inv) where rw ="+i+"";

       rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
 if(rs.next()){


            jTextField1.setText(rs.getString(1));
            jTextField2.setText(rs.getString(2));
            jTextField3.setText(rs.getString(3));
            jTextField4.setText(rs.getString(4));

          }



       i++; 
       rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
       if(rs.next()){


            jTextField5.setText(rs.getString(1));
            jTextField6.setText(rs.getString(2));
            jTextField7.setText(rs.getString(3));
            jTextField8.setText(rs.getString(4));

          }
```

I am new to java so pelase excuse my newbie mistakes

Comment: Add your code and we will see.

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly set text to your `jTextField` intance inside your loop otherwise your `jTextField` won't get updated. But temp those text in variable, then set it to `jTextField` after your loop ends. And don't use `'if'` rather `'while'` , because you want to iterate each row in database

```
 String SQL = "select CATEGORY,ITEM,QTY,Avg_Price from (select CATEGORY,ITEM,QTY,AVG_PRICE, rownum rw     from final_inv) where rw ="+i+"";


String text [] = new String [10]; // just for temp the strings

      rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
     while(rs.next()){

               text[1] +=rs.getString(1);
               text[2] +=rs.getString(2);
               text[3] +=rs.getString(3);
               text[4] +=rs.getString(4);

              }
                  jTextField1.setText(rs.getString(text[1] ));
                jTextField2.setText(rs.getString(text[2] ));
                jTextField3.setText(rs.getString(text[3] ));
                jTextField4.setText(rs.getString(text[4] ));



           i++; 
           rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
          while (rs.next()){

               text[1] +=rs.getString(1);
               text[2] +=rs.getString(2);
               text[3] +=rs.getString(3);
               text[4] +=rs.getString(4);


              }
                jTextField5.setText(rs.getString(text[1]));
                jTextField6.setText(rs.getString(text[2]));
                jTextField7.setText(rs.getString(text[3]));
                jTextField8.setText(rs.getString(text[4]));
```

Comment: have you declare String text [] = new String [10]; ?? what's the error ?? the array of String will explain that don't update JTextField in a loop rather than use variable to catch all those strings and then you can set those strings to JTextField

Comment: I get the error: 
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet.next was not called

Comment: I declared everything and after I get the error shown above

Comment: then the error comes from ResultSet which is producing  java.sql.SQLException

Comment: oh yeah close your first ResultSet before calling the other one , rs.close() before the second rs=stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

Comment: now i get this error : java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name